# sequelize continue transaction after loop

Tags: javascript, express, transactions, sequelize.js

I have multiple loop in transaction chain code, but after loop done transaction immediately commit the chain and not continue to next query. my code is something like this:

```
        return sm.sequelize.transaction(function (t) { 
          return Room.create({
            room_type: req.body.room_type
            },{transaction: t}).then(function(roomtype){
           for (i=0;i<room.length;i++){ 
               return Roomtype.create({
                   name : req.body.roomtype[i]
                    },{transaction: t}); //my transaction only work untill here and commit after that
           }
           for  (i=0;i<another.length;i++){ //I need to continue my query to second loop here
               return User.create({  
                 email :req.body.email[i]
               },{transaction:t}); 
          }
        }).then(function(result){
        }).catch (function(err){
        })
     })
```

so how to make the transaction after loop go to next loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that as soon as you use a `return` statement, the function is over. No more iterations of your `for` loop will run, and neither will the second loop. You need to do this without returning in the middle of your loops.

---

As long as the transaction order isn't important, the best way to do this is to use `Promise.all`, which takes an array of promises, and returns the results of all of them once they are all done. Keeping the rest of the logic you have above, it would look like this:

```
return Room.create({ 
  room_type: req.body.room_type 
}, { transaction: t })
  .then(function (roomtype) {
    const promises = []

    for (let i = 0; i < room.length; i++) { 
      const promise = Roomtype.create({
        name : req.body.roomtype[i]
      }, { transaction: t })
      promises.push(promise)
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < another.length; i++){
      const promise = User.create({  
        email :req.body.email[i]
      }, { transaction: t })
      promises.push(promise)
    }

    return Promise.all(promises)
  })
  .then(function (results) {
    . . .
  })
```

I would go a step further though and replace the for loops with `map`. This is not strictly necessary, but will clean up your code a lot:

```
return Room.create({ room_type: req.body.room_type }, { transaction: t })
  .then(function (roomtype) {
    return Promise.all(req.body.roomtype.map(function (type) {
      return Roomtype.create({ name: type }, { transaction: t })
    }))
  })
  .then(function (roomResults) {
    // Do the same thing for creating users here
  })
```

---

Alternatively, if order *is* important, you are probably going to have to do something like a recursive function that will go through each Promise in order.

```
const createRooms = function (transaction, types, index = 0) {
  return Roomtype.create({ name: types[index] }, { transaction })
    .then(function (result) {
      if (index < types.length - 1) {
        return createRooms(transaction, types, index + 1)
      }
      return result
    })
}
```

You would then call that function in your code:

```
return Room.create({ room_type: req.body.room_type }, { transaction: t })
  .then(function (roomtype) {
    return createRooms(t, req.body.roomtype)
  })
  .then(function (result) {
    // Do the same thing for creating Users here
  })
```